# Non linear development and version control on function based database

Tags: postgresql, version-control, liquibase, flyway

I'm working on a web application of which the backend is highly based on database functions, i.e. much of the business logic happens in Postgres PLV8 functions. (And for better or worse, we are stuck with this structure.)

Currently, we are using Flyway for managing the function code. And that works quite well if everything remains linear. However, imagine the following situation:

Given a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.feed_dog()
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$BODY$
   plv8.execute("SELECT prepare_cat_food()");
   plv8.execute("UPDATE dog SET hunger_status = 'good'");
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plv8;
```

Let's assume this function is deployed to production today and tomorrow we start working on our new feature "dog food health checking" (for "normal" code living on the file system, we create a Git branch for that. For the DB: Maybe a new database?). 5 days later the function in the new feature branch might look like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.feed_dog()
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$BODY$
   plv8.execute("SELECT dog_food_health_check()");
   plv8.execute("UPDATE dog_food_health SET 'status' = 'healthy'");
   plv8.execute("SELECT prepare_cat_food()");
   plv8.execute("UPDATE dog SET hunger_status = 'good'");
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plv8;
```

However, we do not deploy yet, since important parts are missing.

Now, on the very same day, someone discovers that we had mixed up dogs and cats, doing `prepare_cat_food` instead of `prepare_dog_food`.

So, a Hotfix is done, using a Flyway migration which will completely overwrite the whole function `feed_dog`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.feed_dog()
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$BODY$
   plv8.execute("SELECT prepare_dog_food()");
   plv8.execute("UPDATE dog SET hunger_status = 'good'");
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plv8;
```

So, if I apply that migration to the "dog food health checking" branch all new features developed in the `feed_dog` function will be overwritten by the Flyway migration.
Instead, what we would need is a Git-style merging and conflict-solving mechanism which would, in this case, stop at the line `plv8.execute("SELECT prepare_dog_food()");` and require manual review, so that in the end, the new features would remain there with the bug fixed.

How do we do that with Flyway?

Or does it work with Liquibase? They have somehow a branching concept, but I didn't understand so far how it works for non-linear development.

Comment: if you want git mechanism, use git I would say. sqitch offers some not linear deployments, but it wont resolve conflicts for you either...

Comment: @Vao Tsun And how exactly us Git? Copy&paste each function each time you change something is more than annoying. Writing a script for that is also non-trivial, I'd say.

Comment: well. flyway has versions afaik. so f you run same version from different git branch it will say it is already installed?..  same for sqitch - if you have a name deployed, it wont redeploy it. so the easiest way is using branches and installing new funcyion definition by siply running sql from branch. `psql -f ddl.sql` or alike

Comment: @Vao Tsun I don't get it. Running `psql -f ddl.sql` will do the same as Flyway: overwrite an existing function no matter what branch they came from etc. If function definitions diverged on the way, the last branch to run `psql` will win and all previous changes will be gone. What I would need is an automatic approach: Put each DB function to a file on the file system. Commit and push them via Git. Solve conflicts when pulling. Put all function definitions back to the DB via SQL. However, I don't know of anything like that and developing myself would take weeks I'd guess.

Comment: 1. checkout to branch 2. execute sql, changing the definition in db. 3 after some time checkout to other branch and do the same - rewriting the definition of function in db. conflicts and merges are done by git on merging branches. and true - most probably I just dont understand the question - sorry

Comment: @Vao Tsun Ok, got it. However, how does the function definition get into Git? As I said: either copy&paste each time (which is annoying) or spend one or two weeks an developing a script. I had hoped for existing solutions.

Comment: sorry @cis I no longer understand I'm afraid. I thought you would create branch from origin and develop it. to make a hot fix you create other branch. when you ready to merge them, you do so. git takes care on coflicts and so.I dont see any copy/paste here

Comment: Well, right now about about 300 functions are stored in the DB. In order for Git to "take care" of them, they have to go to the file system in some way. Then you can commit, push, merge whatever in Git. However, you have to repeat that process for each change: Any edit in functions also happen in the DB (mainly with pgAdmin). So, after you have edit a function in Postgres, you have to copy them to the file system, Git commit, push etc. It's definitely possible to do that with a script of some kind - but I estimate about a week of work.

Comment: if you modify functions online in db, of course you need to copy paste to FS. I totally agree. you can monkey hack it with keeping all functions in one schema with no other objects. getting all functions to fs will be as easy as `pg_dump -s -n functions_schema`. I understand I'm not offering anything revolutionary here. but if you want Git to care the git stuff, you need git and thus dump definitions to fs - script to do that will be more or less ugly, but is inavoidble - git will not compare functions connecting to db itself

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem right you need a combination of two techniques:

(1) Keeping each function in a source code file:
You need this to make use of the conflict-solving capabilities of your version control system.

(2) Support for out-of-order migration in Flyway:
How to achieve this is described in an excellent article here:
http://www.jeremyjarrell.com/using-flyway-db-with-distributed-version-control/

Basically what you need to do is after every change to the function you have to create a Flyway migration script in the concerning branch that contains the new version of the function. Given your example this will look as follows in practice:

1. Initial state:

feed_dog.sql in trunk

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.feed_dog()
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$BODY$
   plv8.execute("SELECT prepare_cat_food()");
   plv8.execute("UPDATE dog SET hunger_status = 'good'");
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plv8;
```

2. After you have created the health-checking branch

feed_dog.sql in the branch:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.feed_dog()
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$BODY$
   plv8.execute("SELECT dog_food_health_check()");
   plv8.execute("UPDATE dog_food_health SET 'status' = 'healthy'");
   plv8.execute("SELECT prepare_cat_food()");
   plv8.execute("UPDATE dog SET hunger_status = 'good'");
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plv8;
```

3. After you apply the fix in the trunk:

feed_dog.sql in the trunk:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.feed_dog()
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$BODY$
   plv8.execute("SELECT prepare_dog_food()");
   plv8.execute("UPDATE dog SET hunger_status = 'good'");
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plv8;
```

V20170830_124459_hotfix_dogfood.sql in the trunk:
Same content as feed_dog.sql

4. After you merged the changes of trunk to feature branch:

feed_dog.sql in the feature branch:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.feed_dog()
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$BODY$
   plv8.execute("SELECT dog_food_health_check()");
   plv8.execute("UPDATE dog_food_health SET 'status' = 'healthy'");
   plv8.execute("SELECT prepare_dog_food()");   -- Merged here
   plv8.execute("UPDATE dog SET hunger_status = 'good'");
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plv8;
```

V20170831_135559_merged.sql in the feature branch:
Same content as feed_dog.sql

feed_dog.sql is the source code file for the function feed_dog(). The "V" files are the migration scripts with the naming convention according to the recommendations in the article mentioned above.
After you have reintegrated the feature branch Flyway will execute V20170830_124459_hotfix_dogfood.sql and then V20170831_135559_merged.sql.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Wombat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7501483/wombat) [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958696/5291110) understanding...

Use [repeatable migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/repeatable) with each function in its own file. Then Flyway will apply them each time they change. Manage each function file with version control eg `R__feed_dog.sql`. This will avoid copy and pasting the updated function into a versioned migration each time.

Notes from previous experience:

- If you have dependencies between functions then add a number to the start of the description to force flyway to apply in order eg `R__010_framework.sql, R__200_use_of_framework.sql`. This is most important when going into an empty schema
- Turn on debug logging which will output the contents of the repeatable migration in the logs which aids auditing
- Flyway applies repeatable migrations *after* versioned ones so care will be needed if your versioned migrations use the functions